# Cannot call function with parameters using ArduinoMenu

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying print values when Toggle macro of neu-rah/ArduinoMenu is used.
If I don't use any input parameters it works as it should:

```
     void storeConfigValue(){
          Serial.println("");
          Serial.println("-------------");
          Serial.println("config value:");
     }

TOGGLE(conf, Config, "Config ", doNothing, noEvent, wrapStyle 
   , VALUE("1x pre", HIGH, storeConfigValue,noEvent)
   , VALUE("2x pre", LOW, storeConfigValue,noEvent)
  );
```

But when I try to pass a parameter, it gives error:

> void value not ignored as it ought to be

The error code is following:

```
void storeConfigValue(uint8_t a){
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("-------------");
   Serial.println("config value:");
   Serial.println(a);
}

TOGGLE(conf, Config, "Config ", doNothing, noEvent, wrapStyle 
   , VALUE("val1", HIGH, storeConfigValue(1),noEvent)
   , VALUE("val2", LOW, storeConfigValue(2),noEvent)
  );
```

Could you please suggest a correction?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `storeConfigValue` to `VALUE`, you pass the pointer to the function.
When you pass `storeConfigValue(1)` to `VALUE`, you pass the result of the function call, but you declared the function `storeConfigValue` as returning nothing (void). `VALUE` still requires a function pointer. Perhaps you want

```
void storeConfigValue(uint8_t a){
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("-------------");
   Serial.println("config value:");
   Serial.println(a);
}

TOGGLE(conf, Config, "Config ", doNothing, noEvent, wrapStyle 
   , VALUE("val1", HIGH, []{ storeConfigValue(1); }, noEvent)
   , VALUE("val2", LOW, []{ storeConfigValue(2); }, noEvent)
  );
```

Comment: That's what is strange to me. Originaly it was:
 VALUE("val1", HIGH, doNothing,noEvent) 
The "doNothing function is of type result and literally does nothing. I wanted to replace that with a println and in the next step to write the selected value(parameter) into EEPROM.

Comment: @DanRykala See the updated answer.